# Upload image and video in 2 IFormFile Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that i need upload images and videos, for images work perfectly, but if i try upload videos all my model return null. If i upload only images work fine.
I notice if i remove accept="video/*" from imput for video work, but i need this input for videos

```
public class AnuncioDTO
{
    public List<IFormFile> FotoUpload { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> VideoUpload { get; set; }

}
```

controller:

```
     [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SalvarAnuncio(AnuncioDTO model, List<IFormFile> FotoUpload, List<IFormFile> VideoUpload)
    {
    }
```

my razor

```
<form asp-action="SalvarAnuncio" asp-controller="Anuncio" method="post" name="criar-anuncio" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="msform">
    
      <input  type="file" asp-for="FotoUpload" name="FotoUpload"  multiple="multiple" class="form-control"  accept="image/*">

      <input type="file" asp-for="VideoUpload" name="VideoUpload" multiple="multiple" class="form-control"  accept="video/*">
 </form>
```

result if i try upload video, my entire model get null
[image]

if upload only images work fine, but videos is null even i add multiple videos
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
The problem was the size of videos, max size suported is 10mb